Relationship between sensitiviy, probability of detection and Prevalence
Folks, I have 3 questions:

If I know the number of exams performed with a specific test on a group of patients and the test's sensitivity, can I directly estimate the overall probability of detecting the disease in each patient? If yes, this method or variable has a specific term?

Following up on the previous question, let's say I plot the estimated probability of detection (from question 1) against the observed prevalence . Would this curve theoretically increase until it reaches a point where it stabilizes? This would suggest that I've detected all cases when the observed prevalence equals the true prevalence.

Building on the previous questions, if this relationship between sensitivity and observed prevalence holds true, how can I determine a minimum sensitivity threshold? This threshold would indicate a level of confidence that when observed prevalence reaches or exceeds it, there's a high likelihood it's close to the true prevalence. Are there any methods to identify this point on the curve?


Thanks in advance!


Given only the number of tests and test sensitivity, you can't say anything at all about the probability of a positive test in any patient individually, or as a group. Suppose you apply a breast cancer test with 100% sensitivity 1000 times - the probability of a positive test in any particular case is going to be very different if you apply that to 1000 breast cancer patients, 1000 people from the overall population, or 1000 potatoes.

The probability of a positive test is a function of the prevalence, sensitivity, and specificity. The probability of a positive test increases the more positive cases there are (higher prevalence). It won't "stabilize" at any point, you can usually always increase the chance of a positive test by increasing the prevalence up to 100%.

I'm not sure what you're getting at. Sensitivity is only half the story - it describes accuracy among the positive cases, but says nothing at all about test performance among negative cases. Even if you have 100% sensitivity, that says little about whether your predicted prevalence is anywhere near the true prevalence. You can get 100% sensitivity just by having the test always return a positive call, calling 100% of cases positive and yielding 100% sensitivity and 100% prevalence, regardless of the true prevalence in the population. Even a test with 100% sensitivity can have arbitrarily close to 0% accuracy if the positive class is very rare. A test's sensitivity alone cannot be used to measure how well it estimates the true prevalence.



The probability of detection I'm talking about is given the disease is present, what's the probability of being detected? Per example: If I have a true positive patient and a test with 50% sensitivity, If I run more tests, I have a larger probability to detect him as positive. If I rank all patients by this measure and plot it against the observed prevalence, it should increase because more tests, more positives, but when I detect all of then, is stops increasing. Am I completely wrong?

And about what I'm getting: I want to estimate the probability of detection to select cases and controls that have the minimum probability of detection and then be able to use the resulting sample (above this threshold) to study the relationship between cases, controls and variables without the concern of the effect "more tests, more positives". I want to look at a negative value and see that he have a fair chance of being detected as positive and is not, so its close as possible to a true negative/control. Oh, and of course, thank you for answer!

@FelipeLourenço Yes, if you apply a test many times to the same population, the proportion of individuals who have at least one positive test will possibly increase. Not always, if the tests are correlated (e.g. if some real case of disease does not exhibit the marker the test is looking for, you'll never get a positive test no matter how many times you run it). It sounds like you want to use "number of positive tests" per individual as a proxy for "likelihood of disease" which might be reasonable if the tests are truly independent when applied to the same person, but that may not be the case.

That's the problem with my example, I tried to simplify, but my case actually is farms and each event of exam is actually a different cattle in this farm being tested, so yes, they are actually independent. I will put my real case here and hope it help.

I will try to clear some of the confusion.
Sensitivity measures how good your test is at detecting positive cases. What is the likelihood that a positive patient will get a positive test result. E.g. 70% sensitivity means that the test detects the disease in 70% of the positive (affected) patients.
But sensitivity is only half the story (in fact, more like a quarter). There then is specificity. This measures how good the test is at detecting negative cases. What is the likelihood that a negative patient will get a negative test result. E.g. 80% specificity means that the test gives a negative result in 80% of the negative (disease free) patients.
Usually, there is a trade-off between sensitivity and specificity; you can increase one at the expense of the other. A pathological case is a test with 100% sensitivity (but 0% specificity), where you call every result positive (and the reverse pathological case is 100% specificity but 0% sensitivity where you call every result negative). Note that a test with 50% sensitivity and 50% specificity is no better than a coin flip; for every patient, you flip a coin, and say positive for head, negative for tail.
Now, sensitivity and specificity do not depend on prevalence. No matter what the prevalence is, the sensitivity and specificity remain constant. That is because in both case, the subject is assumed to be positive/negative to start, and we evaluate how good the test is at determining this. So your 2nd and 3rd questions do not apply.
Now, there are 2 more "musketeers" to add to the picture. The PPV (positive predictive value) and NPV (negative predictive value) measure how much you can believe a positive/negative result; if a patient gets a positive/negative result, how likely is it for the patient to be truly positive/negative. These last 2 do depend on the prevalence. For a given sensitivity, the lower the prevalence, the lower the PPV will be. For a given sensitivity, the lower the prevalence the higher the NPV will be (and vice-versa for higher prevalences).
Say a test has 95% sensitivity and 95% specificity. If I use such a test on a population where the prevalence is 0.1%, the PPV will be as low as 1.87% (but the NPV will be 99.99%). If instead I use the test on a population where the prevalence is 50% (e.g. symptomatic patients), the PPV and NPV will both be 95%. And if I test a population where the prevalence is 90%, the PPV will be 99.4%, but the NPV will be only 67.9%. And this makes sense; if there is very little chance to beginb with to have a patient with the disease, then a positive result does not mean as much anymore...
You may be interested in looking at this interactive infographics from the BMJ, which illustrates these 4 measures of the "goodness" of a diagnostic (for the case of COVID tests), and demonstrates their interaction, and dependence.lack of dependence on prevalence.

Thank you for the explanation. It actually made me understand I formulated the wrong question. I'm actually not interested in evaluate the sensitivity. I will make another question after digest ot for a while.
